# handleChange with React and Mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

On Step 2 of my web app, an observable string value is assigned inside a MobX store. It is then rendered as a textarea value when the Step 3 component render is triggered.

I have been following the React docs at https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html to handle manual changes to the textarea value but have not been successful.

My textarea in the Step 3 functional component (imported from Semantic UI React):

```
<TextArea autoHeight
          value={ ui_store.final_text_message }
          className={ textarea_style }
          onChange={ () => update_final_textarea }
/>
```

A change handler in the same component:

```
const update_final_textarea = (text_input) => {
    ui_store.set_final_text_message(text_input.target.value);
    console.log(text_input.target.value);
};
```

A mobx action to mutate the observable value controlling the state:

```
set_final_text_message(input_message) {
    this.final_text_message = input_message
}
```

From my console it does not appear that the local change handler is firing. I am backspacing and pressing characters in the textarea but the text from step 2 is locked there, unchanging.

Can anyone spot my current error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking the `update_final_textarea` function inside your inline arrow function. You could just give the function itself to the `onChange` prop instead.

```js
<TextArea
  autoHeight
  value={ui_store.final_text_message}
  className={textarea_style}
  onChange={update_final_textarea}
/>
```

You could also put all the logic inline if you prefer.

```js
<TextArea
  autoHeight
  value={ui_store.final_text_message}
  className={textarea_style}
  onChange={event => ui_store.set_final_text_message(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. Will mark this answered as soon as the limiter expires.